# Single word for "avoiding death"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Is there any single word which encompasses the concept or active avoidance of death, specifically through the use of necromancy, reanimation, or other forms of immortality?

An example sentence would be,

> "Some recurring thematic elements in H. P. Lovecraft's work includes dark familial legacy, other-worldly beings, degeneration, self-destruction, mind control, as well as [the avoidance of death] / [the use of Necromancy, reanimation, and immortality]."

Comment: Can you provide a sentence where you would use this term?

Comment: I am using it to categorize recurring themes of H. P. Lovecraft, in a table format, not in a sentence per se... but I will try to see if I can come up with an example.

Comment: "Some recurring thematic elements in H. P. Lovecraft's work includes dark familial legacy, other-worldly beings, degeneration, self-destruction, mind control, as well as [the avoidance of death] / [the use of Necromancy, reanimation, and immortality]."

Comment: Avoid word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: deathlessness ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might mean the "negation of death" rather than the "avoidance of death".

As in Kyle's answer, the avoidance of death is "self preservation" or "survival" as in Chromane's answer.

"**Amortal**" might also cover the avoidance of death. [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/amortal) has a definition:

> Pursuing a lifestyle that defies the process of ageing

[Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=amortal) goes further:

> Unable to die from disease or age. Immortal if no physical ailment befalls you

The words for the negation of the "effects" of death tend to be specific to particular folklore. Vampire are "undead", zombies are "living dead" or walking dead".

There is also "**reanimated**". [Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/reanimate) give the meaning of "to bring back to life".

Comment: Actually, I think 'amortality' fits exactly what I need! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well, **self-preservation** covers "the avoidance of death", but I'm not familiar with too many words that relate to necromancy. You could derive a word from Lazarus and people would most likely know what you are talking about. **Lazarus** is used a couple of times in science to describe things that 'come back from the dead', for example, lazarus taxa.

Comment: That's a good point, I think it might work, will have to toy around with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

***Immortality***, surely?

> *The quality or condition of being immortal; exemption from death or annihilation; endless life or existence; eternity; perpetuity* (ODO).

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

- "Survival"
- "Resurrection"
- "Reanimation", which generally has less
  positive connotations

Comment: Resurrection and reanimation might be the way to go, but they don't really cover the immortality bit. Will have to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a metaphysical sense: "*transcendence*"

During a fight: "*flee*" or "*escape*"

A more religious term from the Bible: "*transmuted*" or "*raised*"

Answer (score -1):

In that necromancy = [**sorcery**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/necromancy), that's what it is and so that's what it could be called. Pretty simple, really. And given that it's impossible to cheat Death shows you how effective it is. Another word I often use to describe that sort of behavior, is [**superstition**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/superstition):

> ...religious belief based on *fear* or *ignorance* and considered *incompatible with truth or reason*," literally "a standing over," noun of action from past participle stem of superstare "stand on or over; ***survive***,"

- Some recurring thematic elements in H. P. Lovecraft's work includes dark familial legacy, other-worldly beings, degeneration, self-destruction, mind control, as well as **sorcery** / **superstition**.